# Sending an API request to Shopify API without a library/gem/SDK

Tags: rest, shopify, shopify-app

I'm creating a simple shopify app. I'm not using the official libraries and SDK and there's a reason to my madness. I'm using curl.

Say, a user

a) has installed my app and then

b) I've also obtained "access_token" by sending a request to "https://{shop}/admin/oauth/access_token"

Now. I want to send a request to retrieve the user's list of products.  The url for that is "GET https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/products.json"

I've read the documentation but there's ambiguity as in some places it says to use login-pass and in other the api-key.

In other words, **how *exactly* should I send such a request?** What **headers** exactly  should I include ? 
What to do with the access_token?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ambiguity. If you have an oAuth access token, structure your call to the RESTful API as per the instructions. Include your token in the header and make your call:

```
header X-Shopify-Access-Token: {access_token}
```

If instead you use Shopify to create a private App you're issued an API key and password, in which case your calls are structured like this:

```
https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json
```

Comment: well, I have a private test app and yet I've been able to use `X-Shopify-Access-Token: {access_token}` to make an api call and receive a result. Why?

Comment: There could be dozens of things you are doing wrong. Shopify API works. curl certainly works. The advice I gave you was correct, now your challenge is to figure out your problems.